# TimeSlider on Web App does not match the TimeSilder on the underlying Web Map on ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-online-webmap

On ArcGIS Online, I have a hosted Web Map that contains 4 hosted feature layers. Each feature layer has the same number of features and a "Date" field and was published with Time enabled. All the features in a featuer layer has the same date and time for that field.

They have the following attribute tables.

[image][image][image][image]

The web map was published and configured to allow time slider to show the feature layers with time.
[image]

Then I created a web app using Web AppBuilder out of the web map with a TimeSlider widget added. The TimeSlider on the web app has three time steps while that for the web map has four steps as above. Missing the last time step stopped the last feature layer from appearing on the web app.
[image]

I thought the TimeSlider settings on a web app should match the settings on the underlying web map. Any idea?

Edit:
the URLs to them are:

The web map is http://arcg.is/1GHbaD

The web app made from hte web map is http://arcg.is/1vC5zm

Comment: Is it possible to share your webmap?

Comment: @RussRoberts Sure, please see the edited question above.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to reproduce this with the WAB time slider widget. Currently not seeing it with a configurable app template. Please leave the examples up, I have fwd'd this to the WAB team. Thanks!

Comment: @RussRoberts Thanks Russ! I also tried to reproduce this with the Time Aware template (retired) and the issue was gone. So definitely something worth investigation with the Time Slider Widget.